# Two CollisionShape2D's Overlapping

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I am trying to make a game in Godot 4.1.1 and I encountered a problem.
Whenever my player collides with the enemy, their collision shapes overlap and the enemy stays connected to the player.
Here's what it looks like:

[image]

It would stick to me. Collision Shapes are the blue Capsules. Is there a solution?

Comment: Tell me if this explanation makes sense to you: the character is being moving a platform for the enemy that is riding on top of it.

Comment: @Theraot Oh my. Thank you. Let me see if can fix it.